# Extract First chracter of all words except the first one

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, extract

I have list of names and i am tryign to extract the First word then First character of 2nd word and 3rd character of 3rd work and so on...

I was only able to make this formula but it works till 2nd name how to achieve further any help will be much appreciated.

```
=LEFT(D4,FIND(" ",D4)-1)&" "&LEFT(LEFT(D4,SEARCH(" ",D4)-1),1)
```

[image]

[enter link description here][2]

[2]:

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b83hd9lNcjnzGWjbkZbkXFvQLVdOu4YY9_mnLJdP7EQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: updated a link @player0

Comment: @player0 the input is in the column labelled "string" and the output is in the column labelled "Result" or do you think I missed something?

Comment: @SolarMike you didn't, it's just not "easily" scalable I guess (easily like avoiding attaching monstrous strings so it would work for 10+ names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\w+ ")&
 BYROW(B2:B, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(, 1, IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(
 SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(x, "^(\w+) ", ), " "), "[A-Z]"))))))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\w+")&" "&
 BYROW(B2:B, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(, 1, IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(
 SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(x&" ", "^(\w+) ", ), " "), "[A-Z]"))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much but it does not work if cell has single name. @player0

Comment: @HSHO But none of the examples you gave have a single name. Why are you finding obstacles or is this a question with limitless creep? In which case we tend to stop playing.

Answer (score 1):

So, took only two of your examples as I don't have time to type them all in, but this works:

```
LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1)-1)&" "&MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1,1)+1,1)&IFERROR(MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1,FIND(" ",B1,1)+1)+1,1),"")
```

[image]

I used mid() instead of your left(left( construct and find() to find the second and third spaces.

The iferror is to not have an error when the third name does not exist.

You can expand this for 4 names :) good luck.

Comment: Hi thank you for sharing an answer but what if a name has more words like more than 3. It will take the 4th or 5th word first character and it gives an error if string has only single name.

Comment: @HSHO As I stated in my answer, I have shown how to do this for 3 and I left you to expand it for 4 or more, just a question of finding the position of the spaces which I have showed clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation of regex you can try out:

`=INDEX(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B21,"\w+")&" "&MID(REGEXREPLACE(PROPER(B2:B21),"[^A-Z]",""),2,2^99)))`

-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game, but I think this would be a clean way of extracting those letters, without barfing on single words or blank cells:

```
=iferror(regexextract(B2,"\w+ ?")&regexreplace(mid(proper(B2),2,99),"[^A-Z]",""))
```

...or as an array formula:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( 
  regexextract(B2:B, "\w+ ?") & regexreplace(mid(proper(B2:B), 2, 99), "[^A-Z]", "") 
) )
```